# node.js - this instance gets updated?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js. I understand that "before waiting" i.e. before fileRead method returns a value "data" should be undefined, but shouldn't it hold a value after it has waited for one second and surely the fileRead function must have returned a value by now. Please find code below..

Here is a simple code to read file in fileReader.js :

```
exports.fileRead = function(callback){
    var fs = require('fs');

    var f;
    var b = new Buffer(10000);

    fs.open('package.json', 'r', function(err, handle){
        f = handle;
        console.log("reading");

        fs.read(f, b, 0, 10000, null, function(err, bytesRead){
            console.log("read complete!");
            fs.close(f);
            callback();
            console.log("returning");
            return b.toString('utf8',0,bytesRead);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is a file that "imports" fileReader "module" (let me know if my terminology is wrong) :

```
var filePrinter = require('./fileReader.js');
var data;
data = filePrinter.fileRead(function(){
    console.log("before waiting -\n"+ data);
});

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("after waiting -\n" + data);
},1000);
```

console spits this when running :
reading
read complete!
before waiting -
undefined
returning
after waiting -
undefined

I know the below code using callback to pass a parameter would work just fine but what is the issue in above code?

```
//fileReader.js
    exports.fileRead = function(callback){
        var fs = require('fs');

        var f;
        var b = new Buffer(10000);

        fs.open('package.json', 'r', function(err, handle){
            f = handle;
            console.log("reading");

            fs.read(f, b, 0, 10000, null, function(err, bytesRead){
                console.log("read complete!");
                fs.close(f);
                callback(b.toString('utf8',0,bytesRead));
            });
        });
    }
```

//=============================

```
    var filePrinter = require('./fileReader.js');

    var data = null;
    data = filePrinter.fileRead(function(b){
        data = b;
        console.log("before waiting -\n"+ data);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("after waiting -\n" + data);
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the above code is that the value you return from callback is never used ( and not meant to be used) - look at how callback is invoked from [fs.read](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cc08106d6283040fc4c58005b639dae366b18b67/lib/fs.js#L459)

Comment: So would it be right to say functions should not return values instead always pass parameters through callbacks? My understanding was that `fileRead` function is returning a string    -    `return b.toString('utf8',0,bytesRead);`    and `data` should hold what is being returned by `fileRead()`.

Comment: Imagine that you called your friend and ask phone number of another friend. Now "call back" with the number is what you would expect from him, not writing number down on a (remote) piece of paper. In general, yes, in async handlers you do `callback(null, result)` in contrast to sync ("stack based") `return data`

Answer (score 0):

Your `fileRead` function never returns anything, and so the result of calling it is `undefined`. The `return b.toString` you have is from the *callback function* you've given `read`.

To make this work, you need to modify `fileRead` to pass the data to its own callback function:

```
exports.fileRead = function(callback){
    var fs = require('fs');

    var f;
    var b = new Buffer(10000);

    fs.open('package.json', 'r', function(err, handle){
        f = handle;
        console.log("reading");

        fs.read(f, b, 0, 10000, null, function(err, bytesRead){
            console.log("read complete!");
            fs.close(f);
            callback(b.toString('utf8',0,bytesRead)); // <==== Here
            console.log("returning");
        });
    });
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
var data; // No need for = null here, but you could add it back if you want
filePrinter.fileRead(function(b){         // <== Data received by callback as `b`
    data = b;                             // <== Now assigned to `data`
    console.log("in callback -\n"+ data);
});
```

The appropriate place to *use* `data` is from within that callback, not a `setTimeout` callback, and in fact there's little reason to have the `data` variable at all — just use `b` within the callback.